# How should I use debug.print in C#

Tags: c#

In VB, we can use debug.print to print the text in a console, but how do we do the similar thing in C#? The objective is to test the written class.

Comment: @TomTom Debug outputs are adequate for quick testing. Please don't assume that everyone has the resources or need to use unit testing frameworks.

Comment: @mason you don't need a framework to write unit tests.  You just _programatically_ look at results rather than looking at printed output.

Comment: @DStanley Regardless, the question is over how to write to the debug console, not a request to be ridiculed or an attempt to spark a debate about how to debug a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SolutionsCS - that will write to the Console, not the Debug Console. If you then run the code in a non-debug environment it will still print out, which isn't really what you want for debugging messages.

Debug messages appear in the Output window if you select "Show Output From Debug".

If you want to see your debug messages without all the other cruft go to `Tools->Options->Debugging->General` and check `Redirect all Output Window text to the Intermediate Window` and, if the Intermediate Window is closed, follow xPert_Umer's instructions.

Answer (score 9):

Use [Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline) to write debug output.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("My text");
Debug.WriteLine("My text"); //assuming you have using System.Diagnostics
```

The output will be displayed in your IDE. Assuming Visual Studio, it will write to the Output window when you run the project. If you don't see the Output Window try `View -> Output` from the menu bar. When you see the Output window, make sure "Show Output From **Debug**" is selected.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `System.Diagnostics.Debug` and/or `System.Diagnostics.Trace`. Pay attention to the difference (normally) between debug and release configuration.

Furthermore you might want to check out a logging framework like nlog or log4net.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Debug.WriteLine` or `Console.WriteLine`.

Or write appropriate unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` to write text to the debug output. When you compile in release mode, these calls will be removed.